# Link EF to non database objects

Tags: c#, entity-framework

How can a create relationships with entity framework to non database objects. I generated my models and mappings with the power tools [Here is the link of power tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/72a60b14-1581-4b9b-89f2-846072eff19d).

This is mainly to accommodate for a lack of normalisation in a legacy system. I have a partial class setup in order to sustain any changes I make.

To elaborate:-

**EfObject** (generated from database) could have several addresses all in the same table (poor normalisation)

**HomeAddressObject** (Not to be stored in Database)

**CorrespondanceAddressObject** (Not to be stored in Database)

I want to relate to these objects with a means of possibly having them as database tables in the future, however for now they simply need to summarise the data in the main EfObject and make it more convenient to edit.

Comment: Create relationship ? What kind of relationship ? What non database object ? Would appreciate a piece of code to illustrate your need

Comment: Take a look at partials and the `[NotMapped]` attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As CodeCaster suggested above. I was already using partial classes in order to persist my changes after code generation, however I was not familiar with the [NotMapped] attribute.

This has prevented EF from throwing it's toys out the pram!